# Connect to website using nodes

Tags: java, dom, jtidy

I'm trying to write a program that will connect to a website, get the source code, look for the `<body>` tag using nodes. Within that tag there are three "textfields" that I want to input values in, and stream it back to the website.

I got so far to finding the `<body>` tag, but now I'm actually clueless.

```
try
{
  Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Document docx = tidy.parseDOM(new URL("http://www.clubvip.co.za/Login.aspx").openStream(), baos);
  Node n = docx.getFirstChild();
  System.out.println(n.getNodeName());
  n = n.getFirstChild();

  System.out.println(n.getNodeName());
  while (n != null)
  {                     
    while (n != null) {
    if (n.getNodeName() != "body") {                        
        n = n.getNextSibling();                         
        System.out.println(n.getNodeName());
```

Comment: Have you considered using JSoup?  It's designed for web scraping like this and imho provides a nicer interface that the DOM (and more importantly handles all sorts of nasty broken HTML).

Comment: Thanks, will try the JSoup tonight. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get those tags directly by using

```
docx.getElementsByTagName("tagname")
```

See the documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29)

This will return a NodeList you can iterate through.